# Erro ao carregar imagem através da Web API

Tags: html, imagem, http, front-end, get

Tenho uma API Rest e ela me retorna todos os dados de um usuário, inclusive sua imagem. Eu consigo achar a imagem no caminho do diretório, mas não consigo carregar na página.

**Html**

```
<img src="../../../../../../wwwroot/arquivos/defaultM.png">
```

Deixei essa defaultM.png para ficar mais fácil a visualização, ali na verdade é sempre uma variável, mas mesmo assim, não funciona para ambos.

**Erro**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) defaultM.png:1
```

O que devo fazer nesse caso?

A imagem existe no diretório! E o caminho está certo, consigo até visualizar a imagem pelo próprio `src` utilizando `ctrl + click`

Comment: A API retorna o caminho relativo da imagem? já tentou ver na aba de network do seu navegador qual o Status a imagem retorna?

Comment: Esse path relativo não me parece correto, mas sem tem uma visão geral do que está sendo feito, é impossível descobrir. O mesmo com a imagem pela API. Sem conhecer a sua estrutura de pastas/arquivos e o que a API está retornando, fica impossível.

Comment: @ThiagoCosta a API me retorna isso: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) defaultM.png:1 | Mas essa imagem existe no meu servidor, ela está lá.

Answer (score 0):

Com base nos comentários, aparentemente a API não está encontrando o diretório do arquivo (erro código 404 geralmente significa que não foi encontrado ou não existe) . Lembre-se, que o diretório tem que ser informado no atributo *src* de acordo com o local aonde está o seu arquivo *.html*.

Sem olhar a organização dos seus arquivos, ou o resto do código é um pouco difícil ter a precisão exata, mas provavelmente o diretório correto deve ser esse:

```
<img src="arquivos/defaultM.png">
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!